# Clear html input preserving back(ctrl+z)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I use jquery to clear content of input:

```
$('input#myinput').val('');
```

everything is fine except for the user cannot use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to obtain the previous text. is there any way to preserve <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> ?

---

is there any way behaves as if it is cleared by user?

Comment: handle keypress event and listen for `ctrl+z`

Comment: try $('input #myinput').val('');

Comment: @NaYaN , it was a mistake in question. i corrected that immediately. thanks

Comment: @Satpal, what to write inside the event function?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose it gets cleared on clicking a button:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var input = $('input#myinput').val();
  $('#button').click(function() {
    $('input#myinput').val('');
  });
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 90 && e.ctrlKey) {
      $('input#myinput').val( input );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="text"/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button" />
```